# What do these apt commands do?

Tags: apt, update-manager, proxy, repository, cache

What do these commands do?

> Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o 
>   Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update 
>   Acquire::http::Max-Age "0"

Answer (score 3):

- The following command, `Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o` **It adds an No-Cache header to APT http requests**.
- This command `Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update` **Used for fixing your local proxy** i guess.
- This command `Acquire::http::Max-Age "0"` **Maximum time to keep packages around for**.

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw, does the first command disable cache forever? What if I install some package through apt after running that command?

Comment: -1 The Acquire::http::No-Cache=True does not disable apt caching features, it adds an No-Cache header to APT http requests, meaning it will not allow webservers to reply with cached contents (to make sure you don't get a server side cached index file).

Comment: @JoãoPinto are you sure??

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't penalize your answer based on a guess. Check "man apt.conf", search for "http" .

Comment: Alright Thank you @JoãoPinto i have updated my answer.

Comment: The first command solved my BADSIG error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the other options.

But, as of today, **`Acquire::BrokenProxy` does nothing**. It has done nothing since 2011 at the very latest. It did nothing in the version of Ubuntu that was current when this question was posted. If you look it up in the `apt.conf` man page, it is not there. If you look for it in the `apt` source code, it is not there. It's not quite using a regular expression to parse HTML, but it most definitely will not solve your problem and should never be used by anyone.

For one brief, shining moment, between 10:59 PM UTC on Friday, April 1st, 2005, [when it sprang fully formed from the head of Michael Vogt](https://github.com/Debian/apt/commit/284c8bbc764fed53bd0f9bc6a42a7521a0c617ce#diff-82b25fd461248155bff763f8f8d6e677191add5b7fa2c85949a6fb1c09c93208R343-R348), and 8:38 PM UTC on Monday, February 20th, 2006, [when he reluctantly had to put it down](https://github.com/Debian/apt/commit/75dd8af14b76bb84a69a927ecae93f60600b9667#diff-82b25fd461248155bff763f8f8d6e677191add5b7fa2c85949a6fb1c09c93208L343-L348), setting `Acquire::BrokenProxy` would force APT to always re-download the signature file for a package repository, instead of just asking to be sent it if it had been modified. Presumably this is because some "broken" proxies were just sending the old version of the file even when it has changed.

This is all it has ever done, as far as I can tell. You can `git clone https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt.git` and `git log -S "BrokenProxy"` in there to find commits that add and remove this string to/from the APT source code; I only count the two.

This feature first came out in APT version `0.6.35ubuntu1` and would have last been available around APT version `0.6.43.3`, going by the state of the changelog file at those commits. Digging through the `Packages.gz` files on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com, it looks like it should have had an effect on **Ubuntu 5.04 (Hoary Hedgehog)**, **Ubuntu 5.10 (Breezy Badger)**, and **Ubuntu 6.06 LTS (Dapper Drake)** (which has `0.6.40.1ubuntu9`). Version 6.06 was an LTS release that went out of support in 2011. After 2011, or on any Ubuntu that is 6.10 (Edgy Eft), with apt `0.6.45ubuntu14`, or later, nobody has had any business whatsoever using this option.

However, `Acquire::BrokenProxy` remains a popular `apt.conf` option to this day. It got its humble start in December 2005, when its author suggested it as a troubleshooting approach in [an Ubuntu bug report about BADSIG errors](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/24061#yui_3_10_3_1_1652226092361_282). Over the next few years, many lost souls found their way to this bug report, and a few tried passing `-o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true` to their package managers, following an encouraging 2006 report by a user that it had worked for them. Despite a couple of subsequent reports that the option did not (and, depending on Ubuntu version, most likely could no longer) help, in 2009-2010 the option made the rounds on [blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20091212164529/https://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html) and [forums](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/hash-sum-mismatch-debian-781878/), and by 2012 it had been posted back on the BADSIG bug as part of ["the fix"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/24061#yui_3_10_3_1_1652226092361_872) for a misbehaving proxy.

In 2013, two major technologies arrived on the scene that changed computing forever: the Docker container management system, and [the `99fixbadproxy` APT config file](https://gist.github.com/trastle/5722089/revisions):

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "0";
Acquire::http::No-Cache=True;
Acquire::BrokenProxy=true;
```

Soon, people began combining the power of these two technologies, presumably because Docker image building is an `apt` stress test and the other two options actually do something useful. Today, the `99fixbadproxy` file, with this option **that has never had any effect in any Ubuntu version that has ever been available as a Docker image**, [can be found in Dockerfiles all over Github](https://github.com/search?l=Dockerfile&q=99fixbadproxy&type=Code). It has even ascended to become part of Github itself: if you use Github Actions to run tasks on Ubuntu, [your Ubuntu machine will be configured with `Acquire::BrokenProxy` by a `99fixbadproxy`-descendant](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/1457fb6402aaad8508d16a8968106b628368867f/images/linux/scripts/base/apt.sh#L17-L22).

Truly, it is impossible to underestimate the power of the `Acquire::BrokenProxy` option. It's completely inert, it comes attached to other code that may or may not help resolve an intermittent failure, and it looks plausible enough that hardly anyone, present company excepted, has ever thought to question its presence.